# Fastest way to get a large MS SQL Server table into BigQuery

Tags: python, sql-server, google-bigquery

I have an MS SQL Server database with 1200 tables of varying size. The total amount of data is around 2TB and the largest table is around 400GB. Once every three months I need to get this data into BigQuery in an automated way. The data does not have to be transformed in any way, but the process cannot be manual and I have no access to the Windows Server itself.

Currently this is being done with a Dataproc (Spark, Scala) cluster that has 80 CPU's and 1,4TB RAM. This is very wasteful to me though as it's a simple transfer of data.

What I'd like to do instead is retrieve the data using Python and write it into Avro files which I can then load into BigQuery very fast. My problem is that initial tests using pyodbc on a single table show that I get great speeds for the first few seconds (60MBit), and then it drops to around 6MBit. If I do this for 3 tables in parallel (distinct connections), it is the same pattern, but it drops to 3x6=18MBit.

Bonus-info: This takes place over a corporate VPN tunnel between GCP and AWS.

So my questions are:

1. Does MS SQL Server throttle connections after an initial burst?
2. Is there a better way to transfer the data using Python?
3. Is there a better way to transfer the data using something else?

Here is the code I used for the test:

```
import csv
import sys
import tracemalloc
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime

tracemalloc.start()

test_table = sys.argv[1]
fetch_rows = 1000  # Avg 6MBit
output_file = f'{test_table}.csv'
delimiter = ';'
quote_char = '"'
print('Connecting')
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                            'Server=X;'
                            'Database=Y;'
                            'uid=Z;'
                            'pwd=W')

print('Connected')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print('Selecting')
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {test_table}")
print('Executed')
with open(output_file, 'w+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quote_char, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerow([x[0] for x in cursor.description])  # column headers

    rows = cursor.fetchmany(fetch_rows)
    rows_written = 0
    while len(rows) > 0:
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)
            rows_written = rows_written + 1

        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        print(f"{datetime.now()}: {rows_written} rows written. Current memory usage is {current / 10 ** 6}MB;"
              f" Peak was {peak / 10 ** 6}MB")
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(fetch_rows)

    cursor.close()

tracemalloc.stop()
```